# How to change firefox font size in command line?

Tags: firefox

[image]

I can change the font in GUI. I am making a post installation script that set all customization of the newly installed system. So, I need to do this in command line so that I can include this in my script.

Comment: I love that kind of work!  I do the same at each LTS release for my personnal computers. Do you plan to share it?

Comment: @cmak.fr see https://github.com/al2helal/dotfiles/blob/master/postInstallation_18.04.sh

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the value(s) name(s) with `about:config`

By tunning only the font size to 12, I found `font.size.variable.x-western`

2. Tune your profile `prefs.js` file

`~/.mozilla/firefox/<DefaultProfile>/prefs.js`

You can get the default profile folder name with this

`cat ~/.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini | grep 'Path=' | sed s/^Path=//`

insert the line

`user_pref("font.size.variable.x-western", 12);`

3. A good way will be to customize a template profile while watching for differences saved in prefs.js (ie save default pref.js and compare with customized one with a tool like Meld)

Comment: Your answer need some modification. In your process user interference is needed. Please give a automated answer.

Comment: this is pretty easy to do with some basic scripting skills ... you got the keys about how to do what you plan : add config info to prefs.js file ... you just have to script it